# Browsing Hdfs Filesystem from UI

Tags: python, hdfs

How to browse HDFS File-system from an UI like Hue does using python?
I want to list hdfs files from simple html UI

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't involve Python, but you can view this from the NameNode's web UI using "Utilities -> Browse the file system", located at `http://your-namenode:50070/explorer.html` (assuming default http port of 50070)

Comment: Hue is using python to display HDFS file-system on dashboard. I want to use the same to select Hdfs files from Dashboard and i want to use Python .

Comment: It sounds like you probably want to explore the `hdfs` package for Python, which provides programatic access to HDFS: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hdfs

Comment: Using webhdfspy i want to display the files on Dashboard . Like we browse our linux filesystem from html using <input id="a" name="a" type="file">, i want to do similar for HDFS filesystem.